# FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml

Добавил в разметку `FloatingActionButton`:

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMain"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pl">
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Выводит ошибку:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Помогите разобраться в проблеме, буду очень признателен.

Comment: ну во первых убедимся что подключена 'com.android.support:design`, да и унаследоваться от `AppCompatActivity` не помешало бы

Comment: 'com.android.support:design  подключена
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}

Comment: ну а `Activity extends AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: MainActivity extends FragmentActivity,  использую фрагменты

Comment: Ещё надо `support-v7` либу подключить

Comment: Подключил, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1):

В Android Studia когда создаете новый проэкт один из вариантов идет с `FloatingActionButton`. Запустити и сравните со своим.

Comment: сравнивал, вродь бы то, что нужно мне, там нет отличий

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить версии всех библиотек на максимальные. Gradle должен примерно так выглядеть (`buildToolsVersion` тоже последнюю надо взять и не забыть про имя вашего пакета(applicationId)):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ТУТ.ВАШ.ПАКЕТ"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: не знаю, что случилось, но само направилось)) но все равно, спасибо!))

Comment: Скорее всего дело было в старой версии `design` либы. Думаю, если вы проверите сейчас свой проект с строкой `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' ` то оно опять упадёт с вашей ошибкой.

Comment: Нет, была версия изначально compile'com.android.support:design:22.2.0', но попробовал новую версию, приложение упало с ошибками Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'

Comment: @roma библиотека *support-v4* подключается к библиотеке *appcompat-v7* [как зависимость](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), ее не надо подключать отдельно еще раз в таком случае.